# How to have different Build and Drop directory structures in TFS

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild, directory-structure

I have a TFS build configuration that build a solution with 36 projects. They are categorized in various platforms such as "Tests", "WPF" and "WinRT". I need to have my drop location configured with the following structure:

```
/Solution
    /Tests
        /Project1.dll
        /Project2.dll
        /Project3.dll
    /WPF
        /Project4.dll
        /Project5.dll
        /Project6.exe
    /WinRT
        /Project7.dll
        /Project8.dll
        /Project9.exe
```

I have tried to setup a custom output directory per project and shared the same directory for all projects in a specific platform, but this causes the build to fail when two of those projects copies shared dependencies in the build directory. Since two MSBuild instances can try to copy the files at the same time, one of them can triggers an access denied error because the other instance is still writing the file.

If I could have a different build and drop location structure, I could keep the default structure for the build directory and only have the drop process copy the final files and skip the duplicated dependencies. Is there a way to customize the drop location different structure than the build location? How can I achieve such a setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default TFS Build mashes all outputs together into one directory.

What I typically do is write a powershell script that will move around all the files in that one big directory into the folder structure that I want.  I'll check that script into TFS, and customize my TFS Build to run that powershell script as the last step (right before it copies the folder from $(SourcesDirectory)\Binaries -> $(BuildDropDirectory)).

Comment: I will look into this. It seems like it might be the only solution for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the discussion [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/68620f76-0187-4f3b-a7ef-7507f6d39182) about custom output directories. HTH

Comment: I am already using custom output directories. The problem is that they don't work correctly for what I am trying to achieve. I want to keep the default output directories during build, but I want my drop location to have a different structure. What I want is that all of my projects get built in their own directory and only then merge all the outputs together to create the final package.